# Segmentation fault with std::copy, memcpy works

Tags: c++, copy

I have a strange situation where using std::copy is causing a seg fault where as using memcpy appears to work correctly.

I am creating a `PacketHeader` object inside a Google Test function.

I have confirmed that the data going into the object is valid so I'm probably being stupid and have missed something obvious with the std::copy syntax.

GCC version : 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) 
GTest version : 1.6.0

Also linking with boost::options and libpcap

```
TEST(SetIP, GoodVals)
{


    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t * handle = pcap_open_offline("./test_files/PCAP_Good.pcap", errbuf);

    pcap_pkthdr * header;
    const unsigned char * pkt_data;

    //Load one packet from the PCAP, doesn't matter what
    pcap_next_ex(handle, &header, &pkt_data);

    PacketHeader p(header);

}


PacketHeader::PacketHeader(const struct pcap_pkthdr * aPacketHeader) : prPacketHeader(NULL)
{
    prPacketHeader = new struct pcap_pkthdr;

    //This doesn't work
    //std::copy(aPacketHeader, aPacketHeader + sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr), prPacketHeader);

    //This works
    memcpy(prPacketHeader, aPacketHeader, sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr));

}
```

Comment: I *think* `aPacketHeader + sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr)` gets you to the `sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr)`th element of `aPacketHeader`. Not having used `std::copy` before, I'm going to take a wild guess that you want `std::copy(aPacketHeader, aPacketHeader + 1, prPacketHeader)`

Comment: You could also use `PacketHeader::PacketHeader(const struct pcap_pkthdr * aPacketHeader) : prPacketHeader(new struct pcap_pkthdr(*aPacketHeader)) { }`

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks, yes that would be better!

Comment: In a constructor, the initializer, as proposed by @stefaanv is best.  Otherwise, what's wrong with just assigning: `*prPacketHeader = *aPacketHeader;`?  If `pcap_pkthdr` is a PDD, this behaves exactly as does the `memcpy`; if `pcap_pkthdr` isn't a POD, then the `memcpy` is illegal.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes it is a POD so yes makes a lot more sense to go that way. Good day, learnt how to use std::copy and better syntax for initializing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression

```
aPacketHeader + sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr)
```

doesn't do what you expect it to. It actually adds `sizeof(pcap_pkthdr) * sizeof(pcap_pkthdr)` to the pointer base address.

Remember that `aPointer + something` is the same as `aPointer[something]`.

Either add only `1`:

```
aPacketHeader + 1
```

or typecast to `char*`:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(aPacketHeader) + sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr)
```

---

The obvious solution should of course to use simple struct-to-struct copying:

```
*prPacketHeader = *aPacketHeader;
```

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks for the info, works great! Please could you explain to me why you just add 1?

Comment: @TomP89 Because there is only _one_ packet header.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah yes I'm being dumb, I was thinking it's an array...doh!

Comment: There's no point of using `std::copy` if you're just adding `1` to get the end iterator.  Just use assignment (which is what `std::copy` does for each element anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze Simple solutions are often easy to overlook. :)